# Cordova read html5 video from buffer

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, browser-cache

I have an html5 based webapp with a video tag

```
<video controls>
  <source src="fake.website.com/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

To save on clients data usage I'd like to be be able to cache the video. Currently I do this for images as a basic

```
if(url in cache) var image = '<image src="base64string">';
else var image = '<image src="url">';
```

To avoid downloading the video twice, is there a method to read the video from the buffer to cache it?

e.g.

`video.on('ended', function() { //read video and save to cache});`

EDIT: App is based in Cordova so the browser will be Android/iOS webviews

Comment: Why don't you let the browser do its job?

Comment: @Kaiido "To save on clients data usage"

Comment: It's a Cordova app so I'd like to use a local cache for media to prevent high data usage

Comment: AFAIK most modern browsers cache all media incl. videos

Comment: @hindmost Using Cordova will webview also cache the media as expected for Android and iOS? Persistently over several uses

Comment: I don't know about webviews, but browsers (incl. mobile) will

Comment: It seems that you have to tag your question with "cordova" and "android"

Comment: @hindmost updated